# WinService launching silent installer with elevated privileges

Tags: c#, windows-services, installshield, administrator

We have a WinService installed under Administrator account.

From the WinService, we launch a silent InstallShield installer.

Under what privileges does the installer run? Will it be executed with Administrator privileges (inherited from the WinService) or will it run under the Logged User Account privileges?

Comment: I believe that every process runs with the privileges of the caller, which is in this case the WinService.

Comment: Yes, the only case where a child process runs with privileges other than those of the parent (other than when the parent has specifically requested that this happen!) is when the parent does not have administrator privilege and the executable is marked requireAdmin.  That doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: (Strictly speaking, some parts of the installer may *actually* run in TrustedInstaller context, but that isn't relevant here.  And either way it has admin privilege.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an InstallScript MSI project built with an old version of InstallShield (something before InstallShield 12, such as DevStudio 9 or InstallShield 11.5), typically parts of the InstallScript engine were provided as a service and would run as Logon User. These parts were typically the parts that needed elevation on Windows Vista (and technically needed it on XP, though the Logon User was more likely an Administrator), so this was fixed way back in InstallShield 12 (which includes InstallShield 2008 and up).

Aside from that aberration, pretty much everything you launch will inherit its launching context. If your service is impersonating while it launches the setup, it will be launched as the impersonated user; otherwise it will be launched at the same privilege level as the service.

If you need to verify this interactively, while the process is running, take a look at it with a tool like Process Explorer.